# Async and shared rabbit template

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-async

I have queue config like below

```
 @Bean
   public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
   CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new            CachingConnectionFactory(hostName);
    connectionFactory.setUsername(mqUsername);
    connectionFactory.setPassword(mqPassword);
    connectionFactory.setVirtualHost(virtualHost);
    return connectionFactory;
   }

   @Bean
   RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
    return rabbitTemplate;
   }

  @Bean
  public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
    RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin = new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
    return rabbitAdmin;
  }
```

and I have async config like

```
@EnableAsync
@Configuration
public class AsyncConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        return taskExector();
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return new SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExector() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        taskExecutor.initialize();
        return taskExecutor;
    }

}
```

And in my async method I am using amqp admin and rabbit template bean. So as per configuration I will have 10 threads at max executing tasks, what I have found after a while application hangs and taking dump using actuator I found below information, seems deadlock on use of rabbit template/amqp admin bean from line number. 
Is anything wrong with this approach or how to make sure multiple threads can access those rabbit mq beans.

Versions: Spring boot 1.4.0.RELEASE, Java 8.

My service something like this

```
@Service
public class QDispatcherService implements DispatcherService {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    private AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin;


    @Autowired
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @Override
    public void sendData(Data dataObject) throws Exception {

        try {
            //something on this properties , I have to check if queue exist or there are messages in it to decide to add message in other queue
            Properties properties = amqpAdmin.getQueueProperties(queueName);
            amqpAdmin.declareQueue(new Queue(queueName));
             logger.info("***********************DEBUG 4***********************");
            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName, dataObject);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
{
    "threadName": "taskExector-10",
    "threadId": 77,
    "blockedTime": -1,
    "blockedCount": 317,
    "waitedTime": -1,
    "waitedCount": 379,
    "lockName": "com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException@105f30b9",
    "lockOwnerId": -1,
    "lockOwnerName": null,
    "inNative": false,
    "suspended": false,
    "threadState": "WAITING",
    "stackTrace": [
      {
        "methodName": "wait",
        "fileName": "Object.java",
        "lineNumber": -2,
        "className": "java.lang.Object",
        "nativeMethod": true
      },
      {
        "methodName": "wait",
        "fileName": "Object.java",
        "lineNumber": 502,
        "className": "java.lang.Object",
        "nativeMethod": false
      },
      {
        "methodName": "get",
        "fileName": "BlockingCell.java",
        "lineNumber": 50,
        "className": "com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell",
        "nativeMethod": false
      },
      {
        "methodName": "uninterruptibleGet",
        "fileName": "BlockingCell.java",
        "lineNumber": 89,
        "className": "com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell",
        "nativeMethod": false
      },
      {
        "methodName": "uninterruptibleGetValue",
        "fileName": "BlockingValueOrException.java",
        "lineNumber": 33,
        "className": "com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException",
        "nativeMethod": false
      },
      {
        "methodName": "getReply",
        "fileName": "AMQChannel.java",
        "lineNumber": 361,
        "className": "com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation",
        "nativeMethod": false
      },
      {
        "methodName": "privateRpc",
        "fileName": "AMQChannel.java",
        "lineNumber": 226,
        "className": "com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel",
        "nativeMethod": false
      },
      {
        "methodName": "exnWrappingRpc",
        "fileName": "AMQChannel.java",
        "lineNumber": 118,
        "className": "com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel",
        "nativeMethod": false
      },
      {
        "methodName": "queueDeclare",
        "fileName": "ChannelN.java",
        "lineNumber": 844,
        "className": "com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN",
        "nativeMethod": false
      },
      {
        "methodName": "queueDeclare",
        "fileName": "ChannelN.java",
        "lineNumber": 61,
        "className": "com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN",
        "nativeMethod": false
      },
      {
        "methodName": "invoke",
        "fileName": null,
        "lineNumber": -1,
        "className": "sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor176",
        "nativeMethod": false
      },
      {
        "methodName": "invoke",
        "fileName": "DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java",
        "lineNumber": 43,
        "className": "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl",
        "nativeMethod": false
      },
      {
        "methodName": "invoke",
        "fileName": "Method.java",
        "lineNumber": 498,
        "className": "java.lang.reflect.Method",
        "nativeMethod": false
      },
      {
        "methodName": "invoke",
        "fileName": "CachingConnectionFactory.java",
        "lineNumber": 916,
        "className": "org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler",
        "nativeMethod": false
      },
      {
        "methodName": "queueDeclare",
        "fileName": null,
        "lineNumber": -1,
        "className": "com.sun.proxy.$Proxy166",
        "nativeMethod": false
      },
      {
        "methodName": "declareQueues",
        "fileName": "RabbitAdmin.java",
        "lineNumber": 577,
        "className": "org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin",
        "nativeMethod": false
      },
      {
        "methodName": "access$200",
        "fileName": "RabbitAdmin.java",
        "lineNumber": 67,
        "className": "org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin",
        "nativeMethod": false
      },
      {
        "methodName": "doInRabbit",
        "fileName": "RabbitAdmin.java",
        "lineNumber": 209,
        "className": "org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin$3",
        "nativeMethod": false
      },
      {
        "methodName": "doInRabbit",
        "fileName": "RabbitAdmin.java",
        "lineNumber": 206,
        "className": "org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin$3",
        "nativeMethod": false
      },
      {
        "methodName": "doExecute",
        "fileName": "RabbitTemplate.java",
        "lineNumber": 1394,
        "className": "org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate",
        "nativeMethod": false
      },
      {
        "methodName": "execute",
        "fileName": "RabbitTemplate.java",
        "lineNumber": 1367,
        "className": "org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate",
        "nativeMethod": false
      },
      {
        "methodName": "execute",
        "fileName": "RabbitTemplate.java",
        "lineNumber": 1343,
        "className": "org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate",
        "nativeMethod": false
      },
      {
        "methodName": "declareQueue",
        "fileName": "RabbitAdmin.java",
        "lineNumber": 206,
        "className": "org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin",
        "nativeMethod": false
      },
      {
        "methodName": "sendData",
        "fileName": "QDispatcherService.java",
        "lineNumber": 59,
        "className": "com.mycompany.QDispatcherService",
        "nativeMethod": false
      },

      ....

       "lockedMonitors": [
      {
        "className": "java.lang.Object",
        "identityHashCode": 285810320,
        "lockedStackFrame": {
          "methodName": "invoke",
          "fileName": "CachingConnectionFactory.java",
          "lineNumber": 916,
          "className": "org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler",
          "nativeMethod": false
        },
        "lockedStackDepth": 13
      }
    ],
    "lockedSynchronizers": [
      {
        "className": "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker",
        "identityHashCode": 372417558
      }
    ],
    "lockInfo": {
      "className": "com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException",
      "identityHashCode": 274673849
    }
  },
```

________________________________________________________________________-

New trace

```
{
"threadName": "taskExector-10",
"threadId": 77,
"blockedTime": -1,
"blockedCount": 37,
"waitedTime": -1,
"waitedCount": 1113,
"lockName": "java.io.DataOutputStream@33111fc",
"lockOwnerId": 65,
"lockOwnerName": "taskExector-8",
"inNative": false,
"suspended": false,
"threadState": "BLOCKED",
"stackTrace": [
  {
    "methodName": "writeFrame",
    "fileName": "SocketFrameHandler.java",
    "lineNumber": 170,
    "className": "com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler",
    "nativeMethod": false
  },
  {
    "methodName": "writeFrame",
    "fileName": "AMQConnection.java",
    "lineNumber": 542,
    "className": "com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection",
    "nativeMethod": false
  },
  {
    "methodName": "transmit",
    "fileName": "AMQCommand.java",
    "lineNumber": 104,
    "className": "com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQCommand",
    "nativeMethod": false
  },
  {
    "methodName": "quiescingTransmit",
    "fileName": "AMQChannel.java",
    "lineNumber": 337,
    "className": "com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel",
    "nativeMethod": false
  },
  {
    "methodName": "transmit",
    "fileName": "AMQChannel.java",
    "lineNumber": 313,
    "className": "com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel",
    "nativeMethod": false
  },
  {
    "methodName": "basicPublish",
    "fileName": "ChannelN.java",
    "lineNumber": 686,
    "className": "com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN",
    "nativeMethod": false
  },
  {
    "methodName": "basicPublish",
    "fileName": "ChannelN.java",
    "lineNumber": 668,
    "className": "com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN",
    "nativeMethod": false
  },
  {
    "methodName": "invoke",
    "fileName": null,
    "lineNumber": -1,
    "className": "sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor176",
    "nativeMethod": false
  },
  {
    "methodName": "invoke",
    "fileName": "DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java",
    "lineNumber": 43,
    "className": "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl",
    "nativeMethod": false
  },
  {
    "methodName": "invoke",
    "fileName": "Method.java",
    "lineNumber": 498,
    "className": "java.lang.reflect.Method",
    "nativeMethod": false
  },
  {
    "methodName": "invoke",
    "fileName": "CachingConnectionFactory.java",
    "lineNumber": 916,
    "className": "org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler",
    "nativeMethod": false
  },
  {
    "methodName": "basicPublish",
    "fileName": null,
    "lineNumber": -1,
    "className": "com.sun.proxy.$Proxy166",
    "nativeMethod": false
  },
  {
    "methodName": "doSend",
    "fileName": "RabbitTemplate.java",
    "lineNumber": 1451,
    "className": "org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate",
    "nativeMethod": false
  },
  {
    "methodName": "doInRabbit",
    "fileName": "RabbitTemplate.java",
    "lineNumber": 703,
    "className": "org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate$3",
    "nativeMethod": false
  },
  {
    "methodName": "doExecute",
    "fileName": "RabbitTemplate.java",
    "lineNumber": 1394,
    "className": "org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate",
    "nativeMethod": false
  },
  {
    "methodName": "execute",
    "fileName": "RabbitTemplate.java",
    "lineNumber": 1367,
    "className": "org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate",
    "nativeMethod": false
  },
  {
    "methodName": "send",
    "fileName": "RabbitTemplate.java",
    "lineNumber": 699,
    "className": "org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate",
    "nativeMethod": false
  },
  {
    "methodName": "convertAndSend",
    "fileName": "RabbitTemplate.java",
    "lineNumber": 767,
    "className": "org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate",
    "nativeMethod": false
  },
  {
    "methodName": "convertAndSend",
    "fileName": "RabbitTemplate.java",
    "lineNumber": 754,
    "className": "org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate",
    "nativeMethod": false
  }
```

Comment: You have to show your code how you use `RabbitTemplate` and `RabbitAdmin`

Comment: Added in main question

Comment: Good. Can you share some simple Boot application to play from our side?

Comment: Ya, I can cook something for that, but questions that I have 1) is this thread synchronization issue on rabbit template? As. Can't report on local yet. 2) what exactly that thread dump says? 3) is it possible that since queue being deleted and we try to read property , it's causing this? 4) why it's not timing out, how to set timeout for that on rabbit beans?

Comment: I will be able to answer you when I have that application. And please, explain the reason to create/delete those queues. To be honest that isn't producer responsibility. That is a listener part to worry about queues.

Comment: ya listener is removing queue not us, I have sample app ready to communicate what I am doing with some comments that will help you. How you want me to send it to your way ? ur email ?

Comment: GitHub repo would be the best place. I will fork it , build locally, run and DEBUG.

Comment: https://github.com/stackspring/sample

Comment: Ok! That's great, but I don't see the code to play with test data and really bump to the problem. Thanks

Comment: Artem, that is application that I am writing and producing messages and its when problem encountered, as I said cant reproduce on my local. Consumer application is .net and not in my control but I have mentioned some of its process in comments. Thread dump that I have posted is from real app. My intend to get you this sample application is to communicate on process and identify if anything is wrong in a way I am using async , rabbit mq etc. I know it may not be enough.

Comment: I found this problem when in test env, I didnt see any logs from my service and made sure that those 10 threads were active and application kept accepting tasks but nothing being executed...then I took thread dump and found that its something with rabbit mq...

Comment: Ok. Can you also share a thread dump, not that Boot report? I'll take a fresh look in the morning

Comment: ya I used actuator and and took /dump! that is what I pasted above. Ya we can connect again tomorrow. thanks.

Comment: able to reproduce again and similar lock and line number again indicates when its trying to delcare queue..

Comment: I have commented code that declares queue and call of getQueueProperties that is also indirectly declaring passive queue..I will let it run over night to see if it helps. Problem with this is if queue doesnt exists template is not throwing exception :(

Comment: didnt help and now on conver method, added new trace at end in original question. its blocked state on convert and send.

Comment: Again: what can we do from our side to reproduce? OK. I see now that `send` is blocked. Obviously by some other thread which waits for reply for another call to the channel. So, I that would be really useful to reproduce it on that your application. Describe, please, steps how to be.

Comment: I made thread pool of size1, even then I saw the issue. I will rewrite my mehtod that is being executed to paste here soon.

Comment: Again: your words doesn't help. Please, modify that application on the GitHub to let us reproduce locally to figure out what may be wrong. Thanks

Comment: Worked on coming up with application that we can reproduce on local but no success. I really spent good time. Now one more update. I didn't tell so far we are running on cloud foundry, if it helps. And when we had reproduce this issue in that environment , this time I went to rabbit mq admin console and manually closed connection from console couple times and I saw errors saying channel shutdown and it reconnected and started working! Seems something with how rabbit mq cluster implemented. Also when this issue was there I can see channels status was continuous in running state.

Comment: Artem - issue is resolved. There were changes made in rabbit mq infrastructure and I bind application with new serivce. New service is clusterbased etc (I will get more details between new vs old) but that solved the issue. But this is something can happen anytime in production, how to set timeout for such thing or any other strategy you recommend.  Thread should not wait hanging forever. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Issue is back :( Again all channels can be seen on rabbit dashboard as hanging/running. Once I manually closed connection on rabbit dashboard I saw timeout in app logs and it started working again with new channels. Also here are few links about similar hanging issue

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/rabbitmq-users/channel$20hangs|sort:relevance/rabbitmq-users/YQV9iZsncro/1FvGbRd0t_0J                                                                                      https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/rabbitmq-users/channel$20hangs|sort:relevance/rabbitmq-users/jjlUSaXaj-I/jGUERfuRxrcJ

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unusual to declare the queue on every send; that said, apart from the inefficiency it should work. The stack trace indicates we are stuck in the rabbit client waiting for a reply for the queue declaration. I have seen this when more than one thread is using the same channel, but that should never happen here because the channel is always returned to the cache when the current operation (admin, template) completes and can't be used by multiple threads.

You might want to try the new 4.0.0.RC1 [amqp-client](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rabbitmq-users/Iqx9_D0xWno/7ox3EuC9AwAJ) jar because they have now added logging (which is not available in the 3.x.x client). It might help track things down.

Comment: Thanks I will try to use new version. I want to rule out that this is because some other application trying to use/delete queue same time when we are trying to get either queue props or trying to declare queue. As u said it's waiting on reply from rabbit , does that mean there is nothing like locking of resources because of our custom thread pool for asynchronous, I think it's not but wan to confirm. ( Initial experiment looks if I remove asynchronous nature of my service it's work fine but has to do more testing). And why it's not timing out how to set that for either rabbit operation or for

Comment: I don't know the internals of the rabbit client well enough - you would have to ask that question on the rabbitmq-users google group. I have only seen this before when somebody tried to send a message an a channel that was delivering a returned message - it was a similar deadlock - but I don't see you using mandatory here.

Comment: I am not using amqp lib directly, I am using spring-ampq which is 1.6.1.RELEASE. (spring-boot-starter-amqp spring boot ver 1.4.0.release)

Comment: Right - and spring-rabbit pulls in `com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:3.6.3` transitively - you need to override that dependency with the coordinates described in the google group post I pointed you too. BTW Spring Boot 1.4.2 is available now.

Comment: Issue is still there saw some links of similar issue mentioned before where channel hangs https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/rabbitmq-users/channel$20hangs|sort:relevance/rabbitmq-users/YQV9iZsncro/1FvGbRd0t_0J                                                                                      and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/rabbitmq-users/channel$20hangs|sort:relevance/rabbitmq-users/jjlUSaXaj-I/jGUERfuRxrcJ

Comment: Still troubleshooting but with help of devops we can see this error in rabbit log, they still looking more. and that can cause this hanging issue operation queue.declare caused a channel exception not_found: "no queue 'ourqueueName' in vhost '778fb055-6bd0-405c-913b-11a9925ec2f3'"